# Open Source Calendar Solutions (integrate with Google Calendar)

Tags: javascript, calendar, integration, styling

I'm looking for an open-source javascript solution that would allow me to style a calendar.  So far the best I've found has been http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ the only problem with this is that it doesn't integrate with multiple Google Calendars.  Has anyone seen something that does?